# How to install Apex 19.2?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to install Apex 19.2 on Oracle 18c XE

Here is what I did width sysdba privilege

```
-- Install apex from the corresponding folder
@apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/

-- Change passwords
@apxchpwd.sql

-- Set static files folder
@apex_epg_config.sql F:\software\apex19\

-- Unlock Apex users
ALTER USER APEX_190200  IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER APEX_LISTENER  IDENTIFIED BY Password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER APEX_PUBLIC_USER  IDENTIFIED BY Password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER  IDENTIFIED BY Password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER  IDENTIFIED BY Password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

-- Configure restfull services
@apex_rest_config.sql

-- Set the port
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8181);

-- Grant ACL access privileges
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to 'localhost' and give APEX_190200
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_190200 does not have the privilege yet.
  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = 'localhost' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_190200',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_190200', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to 'localhost'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('local-access-users.xml',
    'ACL that lets users to connect to localhost',
    'APEX_190200', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('local-access-users.xml','localhost');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

All the steps completed successfully, however when connecting to localhost:8181 I'm getting a window asking for a username and a password. I'm expecting the Apex login page to load.

Does anyone know how to solve that please or tell me what I did wrong ? 
I have a blank database running **Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0**

Thanks

Cheers,

[image]

Comment: localhost:8181/apex

Comment: the problem is not this

Comment: i don't think your url is right for apex when running out of xdb, but just something to look into

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmig/configuring-embedded-PL-SQL-gateway.html#GUID-194241A1-B17E-4C83-92D8-B34F110144EE

Comparing it to your code, it seems you missed this step:

```
ALTER USER ANONYMOUS ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```